# Law, English, or somewhere else? Where should these two questions go?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

I have two questions:

1. In many jurisdictions, one can swear or affirm with the same legal implications. Does saying, "I solemnly affirm ..." mean the same thing as "I affirm," thus making "solemnly" somewhat redundant, or does "solemnly affirming" something have religious connotations, thus being similar to swearing?
2. What is the significance of raising one's right hand before making an oath/affirmation?

These two questions definitely feel law-related. However, they're about the communicative *meaning* of actions done in a court of law, so maybe they're more language-related. Do the questions belong in the Law StackExchange, or should I post one or both somewhere else?

Comment: The second one definitely has nothing to do with language. The first one (I think) would be on-topic on Law.SE _if_ you specify the jurisdiction(s). I don't think it's on-topic on either EL&U or ELL because you're asking about the implications in court, not just the meaning of the word. And even if you were asking about the meaning of the word, a dictionary would be a more appropriate tool (they actually have a close-reason for that, IIRC).

Comment: This might be a good question for https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law

Comment: Thanks for all the help, everyone! I decided to post both in the Law Stack Exchange. The "solemnly affirm" question is here: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/77609/i-solemnly-affirm-vs-i-affirm

Comment: And the question about raising one's right hand before swearing or affirming something can be found here: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/77610/what-is-the-significance-of-raising-ones-right-hand-before-making-an-oath-or-af